TooManyFieldsSent Error raised when saving admin.ModelAdmin with TabularInline even with unchanged fields
Whenever I try to save without editing any fields in Author in the admin page, I get a TooManyFields error. I am aware that I can simply set this in settings.py.
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = None 
# or DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = some_large_number 

However, not setting a limit would open up an attack vector and would pose security risks. I'd like to avoid this approach as much as possible.
My admin model AuthorAdmin has a TabularInline called PostInline.
admin.py
    class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
        inlines = [PostInline]

    class PostInline(admin.TabularInline)
        model = Post


Models
    class Author(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        
        def __str__(self): 
            return str(self.name)

    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.title)
     

The reason this error is being raised is that an Author can have multiple posts. Whenever this Author is saved (without any field change), it sends out a POST request which includes the post_id and the post__series_id based on the number of posts under that same author. This can easily exceed the default limit set by Django which is set to 1000.
Is there a way to not include unchanged fields in the POST request upon save? Or a better approach to solve this issue without having to resort to updating DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS?

Is removing the inline an option? You could have a Post admin page with an author filter instead?

The one I posted is just an oversimplification of what I'm trying to solve. The author and post models are just examples but they represent the relationship of the actual models I'm using. But to answer your question, no. Unfortunately, removing the inline is not an option.

Could you try
class PostInline(admin.TabularInline)
    model = Post

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

Can't test it right now, but if you can't edit the item, maybe it's not saved either.

Hi @Benjamin_Mourgues, thanks but I've already tried this approach. Each post is still included when you click on save.
